# adding curent item to pagenavigation

Tags: php

I want to modify: **/plugins/content/pagenavigation/tmpl/default.php**.

There are 2 `<li>` tags, one for "next" and one for "previous".

I want to display the current article's title in a `<li>` between them.

What is the code to show the title of the present article?

```
<ul class="pager pagenav">
    <?php
    if ($row->prev) :
        $direction = $lang->isRtl() ? 'right' : 'left';
        ?>
        <li class="previous">
            <a class="hasTooltip" title="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($rows[$location-1]->title); ?>" aria-label="<?php echo JText::sprintf('JPREVIOUS_TITLE', htmlspecialchars($rows[$location-1]->title)); ?>" href="<?php echo $row->prev; ?>" rel="prev">
                <?php echo '<span class="icon-chevron-' . $direction . '" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span aria-hidden="true">' . $row->prev_label . '</span>'; ?>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php
    endif;
    ?>

    <li class="middle"> code of curent item ?? </li>

    <?php
    if ($row->next) :
        $direction = $lang->isRtl() ? 'left' : 'right';
        ?>
        <li class="next">
            <a class="hasTooltip" title="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($rows[$location+1]->title); ?>" aria-label="<?php echo JText::sprintf('JNEXT_TITLE', htmlspecialchars($rows[$location+1]->title)); ?>" href="<?php echo $row->next; ?>" rel="next">
                <?php echo '<span aria-hidden="true">' . $row->next_label . '</span> <span class="icon-chevron-' . $direction . '" aria-hidden="true"></span>'; ?>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php
    endif;
    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
<li class="middle"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($rows[$location]->title); ?></li>
```